# Issues Defining a Str method

Tags: python, class, methods

I having issues with my below program.I am trying to Define a `__str__` method for this class here so that when an instance of class Student is printed, it prints something of the format: `"My name is ___. I've been in college for __ years and I've written __ programs."` Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, name, years_at_umich=1):
        self.name = name
        self.years_UM = years_at_umich
        self.bonus_points = random.randrange(1000)
        self.programs_written = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is %s. I've been in college for %d years and I've written %d programs" \
            %(self.name, self.years_UM, self.programs_written)
    def shout(self, phrase_to_shout):
        print phrase_to_shout  

    def year_at_umich(self):
        return self.years_UM

    def write_programs(self, progs=1):
        self.programs_written += progs
        return self.programs_written
```

---

If the program is tested against different values it is not executing correctly. Right now only the test for student 4 is passing. Any help would be great!

```
class Student(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_student1(self):
        student1 = Student("Lyra")
        self.assertEqual(student1.__str__(),"My name is Lyra. I've been at UMich for 1 years and I've written 0 programs.")
    def test_student2(self):
        student2 = Student("Aisha")
        student2.write_programs()
        self.assertEqual(student2.__str__(),"My name is Aisha. I've been at UMich for 1 years and I've written 1 programs.")
    def test_student3(self):
        student3 = Student("Ali",3)
        student3.write_programs(4)
        self.assertEqual(student3.__str__(),"My name is Ali. I've been at UMich for 3 years and I've written 4 programs.")
    def test_student4(self):
        student4 = Student("Aja")
        student4.write_programs(12)
        self.assertEqual(student4.programs_written, 12)
        student4.write_programs()
        self.assertEqual(student4.programs_written,13)
```

Comment: And where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an issue, just define a method that would pull what you need. You can easily format it like `"My name is %s. I've been in college for %s years and I've written %d programs."%(self.name,self.years_school,self.programs_written)`. Also your method `year_at_umich(self)` would fail as you have nothing called `years_UM`.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is written in Python 3.6

So I am assuming you want to re-write your **str**() to output custom text. I have stripped the extraneous code not needed to demonstrate this example. This is what I have:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, years_in_school=1):
        self.name = name
        self.years_school = years_in_school
        self.programs_written = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return ("My name is {}, I've been in college for {} years and I've written {} programs!".format(
                self.name, self.years_school, self.programs_written
    ))
```

So first lets break some things down. In your **init**() you have years_school being assigned to years_in_school, why not just make them the same? There really is no need to have two different variables here. Make it like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, years_in_school=1):
        self.name = name
        self.years_in_school = years_in_school
        self.programs_written = 0
```

It can be the same name is the convention when doing your **init**(). I have made the code though match exactly what you have written as I do not know your intent on this, so i found it best not to change it for the example above.

Now lets look at the code that makes what you want happen. So we set **str**() to return exactly what you have asked for and format it simply with the variables you have already created in your **init**(). When you create your object, and go to print() it out, you will see exactly what you are looking for.

Another way to do this is to simply create an entirely new method to handle this. Instead of re-defining **str**() you can simply create a new method called:

```
show_student(self):
    print("My name is {}, I've been in college for {} years and I've written {} programs!".format(
           self.name, self.years_school, self.programs_written
))
```

Then when you call it simply type out:

```
object_name_goes_here.show_student()
```

This would be more preferred, because now anytime you try to print when re-defining **str**() it will always output the string you created vs what you might expect print() to do. I would honestly use defining a new method to handle this over rewriting **str**()

Hope this helps you out. If anyone else knows of a better way, please let me know. I'm always open to learning more. Please see attached picture for output in python console.

[Output in Python Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSqQ6.jpg)

Also as stated in one of your comments, years_UM does nothing because you have no variable called for it. You will want to add that to your **init**() and set to some value, or just call years_school or years_in_school(if you change the code as I have mentioned above) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I took some of them into account and tweaked my code. However, when I try to invoke different test values my code is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your updated code and what you are using to get the error so I can see whats going on

Comment: @SammySmith so any progress on this or . . . . . . .